# Applying the CIScreenBlendMode filter

Tags: ios, cifilter

I want to blend an image with a blue color, using the *CIScreenBlendMode* filter.

For that, I use the following code:

```
-(CIImage*)makeitBlue:(CIImage*)greyImage{
    
    CIImage* outputImage = nil;
    
    //create some blue
    CIFilter* blueGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIConstantColorGenerator"];
    CIColor* blue = [CIColor colorWithString:@"0.1 0.5 0.8 1.0"];
    [blueGenerator setValue:blue forKey:@"inputColor"];
    CIImage* blueImage = [blueGenerator valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    
    //apply a screen filter
    CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIScreenBlendMode"];
    [filter setValue:blueImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:greyImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
    outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    
    return outputImage;
    
}
```

This method makes my app crash and I don't know why.

In its documentation Apple states the following parameters for *CIScreenBlendMode*:

> inputImage | A CIImage object whose display name is Image.
>
> inputBackgroundImage | A CIImage object whose display name is
> Background Image.

I think that is just what I'm providing.

When I replace *CIScreenBlendMode* with *CIMultiplyCompositing*, this code is running fine.

Maybe some of you can spot the mistake I make?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Using a CIImage from CIColor in a CIFilter: getting empty image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903066/using-a-ciimage-from-cicolor-in-a-cifilter-getting-empty-image).

As **user578205** states:

> You should crop the generated image to beginImage size because
>   generated image's size is infinite. I don't know why, but
>   CIOverlayBlendMode isn't tolerant to infinite size

And in a way it makes sense: how could you align two images of which one is of infinite size?